# How delete all components in a div but not itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to delete all the components in a `<div>` but I can't delete the `<div>` itself. My html code is:

```
<div id="home">
  <label></label>
  <label></label>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$('div[id="home"]').empty();
```

But this code it doesn't work because the div is always not empty. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Working fine for me. I think you missed `jquery` reference.

Comment: Should work, check it here, http://jsbin.com/jijexinemo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: check any errors.. in these situations `console` is your friend.

Comment: When do you call your snippet? How div content is loaded? Cannot you btw handle it server side instead?

Comment: Try to put the js code inside ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
$("#home").empty();
```

to remove the div:

```
$("#home").remove();
```

to hide:

```
$("#home").hide();
```

Comment: why is this the best answer? the OP specifically stated that the original div (#home) was not to be deleted. Also - hiding it doesn't delete the contents of the div but alters the display of the div.  - meaning that 2 out of three parts of thispost are not providing the required effect. Just Sayin'

Comment: problem is that removing the div (expressly stated to not ocur) and simply hiding the div (without removing the contents) surely do NOT fall within the scope of the question. I posted $('#home').html(''); early on in this answer trail and wouls submit that is is equally simple, detailed and more in scope to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply doing this:

```
$('#home').html('');
```

then it doesn't matter what the contents of the div are - either all contents will be deleted or the empty div will be replaced by an empty div.

Answer (score 0):

Check the div is empty or not, if it is not empty then empty it.

```
 if ($('#home').is(':empty')){
   $("#home").empty();
 }
```

Comment: I read this : 
*If Home is empty Then make Home empty....*
Don't you forget a 'not' ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned your code should work, Ensure the DOM is ready (All elements are drawn to the page) by enclosing your code in either

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div[id="home"]').empty();
});
```

or the shorthand jquery equivalent

```
$(function(){
   $('div[id="home"]').empty();
}):
```

As sumanta has given an example of, Another easy way to remove all content from inside a node would be to simple set the .html property to equal an empty string

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div[id="home"]').html("");
});
```

For more information on jquery DOM removal see :  http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/

Hope this helps.